# Visual Studio bad controls quality?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, graphics, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and I'm working on a project.

I noticed that whenever a form is shown, its graphics present a relevant quality loss if compared to the visual editor.

Here you can see both versions of the forms. On the left, the editor... while on the right, the built binary during execution:

[image]

Hope someone can give me some informations about this behaviour, and eventually a fix.

Comment: What is the DPI settings of the system at which you are running the app?

Comment: Almost looks like you've applied a blur effect. Do you have any effects enabled for the window?

Comment: Nope guys, I've never applied any kind of effects to my computer. It's strange because I only get this behaviour from Visual Studio itself... and the binaries I build using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms high DPI blurry fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts)

Comment: I don't think that's Visual Studio. Those controls are part of .NET and they have been working fine for me and millions of other people using them :) There might be something funky going on with your computer.

Comment: @MattSieker Hey, thanks for your suggestion. Unluckily after having tried the solution posted in that question, no changes have been applied to my binary... and I can still see it blurry and so on

Comment: @W00dL3cs, did you add the manifest, or the pinvoke? Judging from the comments on that answer, the pinvoke option is deprecated, and no longer works. One thing you could try to see if it is a DPI issue, is, in Explorer, right click on your program, do Properties, go to the compatibility tab, turn on "Disable display scaling", and see if your program still exhibits the same behavior

Comment: @MattSieker Yes I read about the deprecated PInvoke, so I tested with the manifest directly... and no success. Now I've tried to disable the display scaling in the binary properties, and it WORKS! ... Unluckily, not if I run the debugger from Visual Studio etc

Comment: It might be using the settings from the vshost.exe file that's alongside your application. Does the manifest work when not running in the debugger, also? I see from some of my local projects, the vhost file has it's own manifest, so it might be using that over the manifest you added.

Comment: @MattSieker Exactly, the manifest works with the binary, but not via debugger. Any way I can overcome or replace this behaviour?

Comment: I would try either editing the vshost.exe.manifest to include the same directives for DPI, or mark the vshost.exe with the compatibility flag, and try restarting visual studio, since the process hangs around as long as VS is running.

Comment: @MattSieker And that would just be a temp solution? I mean, I should do that to every project I work on etc? :@

Comment: That, or going into the project properties, Debug and then uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". There's a bug filed in Connect about the hosting process ignoring the manifest, but it doesn't look like it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

***process steps:
1-right click on the desktop.
2-Select display settings.
3-Change the size of text,apps and other items100%(Recommended) - Make sure it's 100%.***